# playback sequence of bag files in order

Tags: ros, rosbag, bagfile, play

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I recently created a sequence of large bag files from a single experiment using the chunksize option of rosbag record. Is there a method to play the resulting bag files back to back?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/198762/playback-sequence-of-bag-files-in-order/) by [pnyholm](https://answers.ros.org/users/5202/pnyholm/) on ROS Answers with karma: 97 on 2014-12-02

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Just adding all bag files in play command should work

```
rosbag play recorded1.bag recorded2.bag
```

command plays both bag files one after other, if they are recorded in different time i.e your case.

[doc: rosbag play](http://wiki.ros.org/rosbag/Commandline#play)

---

Originally posted by [bvbdort](https://answers.ros.org/users/9486/bvbdort/) with karma: 3034 on 2014-12-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [pnyholm](https://answers.ros.org/users/5202/pnyholm/) on 2014-12-02**:
Great, I had thought that would play both bags simultaneously but they are in fact consecutive. Thanks so much